# Pandas Read txt with ID duplication on the end

Tags: python, pandas, txt

I would like to ask for help with the following problem:

I need to use a downloaded txt data with this **duplicate id** at the end of the row structure.

```
UID  value1  value2
A01      99      10    A01
A02      29      12    A02
A03      96      14    A03
```

**My desired output would look like**

```
UID  value1  value2
A01      99      10
A02      29      12
A03      96      14
```

How can I use pandas to read this structure and drop the last duplicate column.

fun fact: Without special reading parameters, the UID column becomes index and every column shifts.

I have ideas to do workarounds, but I want to handle the problem in python and looking for a clean solution for this problem.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me working use `index_col=False`, then last column without header is removed:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=False)

print (df)
   UID  value1  value2
0  A01      99      10
1  A02      29      12
2  A03      96      14
```